# Retrieve Context from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-context

I created a class to retrieve comments from a JSON encoding from a PHP file. This class, extends from AsyncTask:

```
public class RecuperarComentarisFoto extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(????);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to show a ProgressDialog while the "doInBackground" proccess is working. But progressDialog constructor, asks for a Context, and I don't know how to provide it.

I'm calling this class from a Fragment, so I can't access the context like this:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyFragmentA.context);
```

The "main" acitivity is called: AndroidViewPagerActivity which extends FragmentActivity.

(By main, I mean that it's the one that is creating the tabs, and managing the navigation between them.)

This is it's code:

```
public class AndroidViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    bar.hide();

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment A"), MyFragmentA.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }

}
```

How can I access the context? Which context should I use? "AndroidViewPagerActivity" context? So how can I access its context from a fragment?

Thank you.

Sergi

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` inside the `Fragment` to obtain a `Context` that you can pass along. That works, as `Activity` inherits from `Context`.

As alternative you can use `getApplicationContext()` to obtain the `Context`.

Comment: Ok, this solved the problem. With your help and some extra googleing, i got it :D. Going to put my final code, so every1 can see the answer implemented.

Comment: Calling getActivity() inside the fragment may result in NullPointerException when used in large scale for some devices. This happens when the call is made before the fragment gets attached to the activity. It also results in memory leaks which can be fatal and hard to find. Go through this to get a better understanding.  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 3):

@heiko-rupp's answer is outdated,
 `Fragment.getContext()` has been introduced in Fragments in API 23.

To pass it around from fragment you have to use, like `this.getContext()`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext() which according to documentations just

> Return the Context this fragment is currently associated with.

Comment: so it won't work in lower apis then and using applicationcontext is better

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now I know something new:

- You've to get the context from the class that instanced the fragment.

You do this by including this in your code in the fragment ("the child").

```
Context cont;
cont=getActivity();
```

So then, once you've the context, you pass it. In my case, I had to pass it a AsyncTask class, so I can show a dialog.

```
new RecuperarComentarisFoto(cont).execute();
```

And to finish this, on the "RecuperarComentarisFoto" class, I created a constructor. As I've read, it's ok to do it this way.

```
private Context mContext;
public RecuperarComentarisFoto(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
}
```

And the magic:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.mContext);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}
```

This all ends with:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A great way without using getActivity() is creating a local nullable variable inside the fragment

### Kotlin

```
private var attachedContext: Context? = null
```

Then in onAttach you correspond the current context to the fragment

```
 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        attachedContext = context
}
```

Lastly when you use it you can check if that context is null, if not you can proceed

```
attachedContext?.let { safeContext -> 
 
  // Safe place that you know context is not null

}
```

As a next step, I have placed the debugger so you can see that the context attached to this variable is the same one as `getActivity()` but the fragments get the context of the parent activity is being contained on

[image]

This is a better way to be cleaner in our fragments and explicitly know where the context is coming from with the lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

FragmentActivity this will give you context of activity and then you can pass it to your AsyncTask.