# getContext() is not working in fragment - android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview, android-studio-2.3

I'm using a fragment for map which I'll use in main activity. But when I pass getContext() as argument, this is not working and showing me the following error. Please help to get rid of this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOQRo.png)

Comment: you should use `getActivity()`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14161920/)

Comment: you should be using getActivity, try to search before posting question

Comment: Use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Thanks #Kidus & #Raut_Darpan

Comment: I've already imported that one... #Enzokie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`.

Comment: Worked, Thanks !

Comment: sorry, I was just looking my old questions... I don't know how to validate answer.