# Unable to retrieve context in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried to find the solution with several resources:

1. [Retrieve Context from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161892/retrieve-context-from-a-fragment)
2. [Using context in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)

But I still got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

---

My current codes:

AnalysisActivity.java:

```
package com.app.component.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.material.components.R;
import com.material.components.fragment.FragmentTabsEvents;
import com.material.components.fragment.FragmentTabsPerformance;
import com.material.components.fragment.FragmentTabsRecommendation;
import com.material.components.utils.Tools;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AnalysisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ViewPager view_pager;
    private TabLayout tab_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_analysis);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Tools.setSystemBarColor(this,R.color.black);

        view_pager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        setupViewPager(view_pager);

        tab_layout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tab_layout.setupWithViewPager(view_pager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(FragmentTabsPerformance.newInstance(), "PERFORMANCE");
        adapter.addFragment(FragmentTabsRecommendation.newInstance(), "RECOMMENDATION");
        adapter.addFragment(FragmentTabsEvents.newInstance(), "EVENTS RELATED TO YOU");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return  true;
    }
}
```

FragmentTabsPerformance.java:

```
package com.app.component.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.material.components.R;
import com.material.components.utils.Tools;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.Line;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.LineChartData;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.model.PointValue;
import lecho.lib.hellocharts.view.LineChartView;

public class FragmentTabsPerformance extends Fragment {

    private Context context;
    public FragmentTabsPerformance() {
        this.context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        List<PointValue> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new PointValue(0, 2));
        values.add(new PointValue(1, 4));
        values.add(new PointValue(2, 3));
        values.add(new PointValue(3, 4));

        //In most cased you can call data model methods in builder-pattern-like manner.
        Line line = new Line(values).setColor(Color.BLUE).setCubic(true);
        List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        lines.add(line);

        LineChartData data = new LineChartData();
        data.setLines(lines);

        LineChartView chart = new LineChartView(this.getContext());
        chart.setLineChartData(data);
    }

    public static FragmentTabsPerformance newInstance() {
        FragmentTabsPerformance fragment = new FragmentTabsPerformance();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs_performance, container, false);

        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_1), R.drawable.image_8);
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_2), R.drawable.image_9);
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_3), R.drawable.image_15);
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_4), R.drawable.image_14);
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_5), R.drawable.image_12);
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_6), R.drawable.image_2);
        Tools.displayImageOriginal(getActivity(), (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image_7), R.drawable.image_5);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have access to a `Context` in the constructor, as the `Fragment` is not yet attached to one. Since you're using that `Context` to instantiate a `View`, why not move that to `onCreateView()`? Also, there's really no need to keep a `Context` field. Just call `getActivity()` wherever you need one.

Comment: Oh I see it.. thanks for the response!

Comment: Yep, that'll work. I would mention, though, that, in the code you've posted, you're not adding that `LineChartView` to anything on-screen, so you're not going to see it. I'm not sure if you just haven't gotten to that part yet.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurred since you called the getActivity() in the construction method when the fragment is not attached to an activity. You may refer to the [API guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) about the lifecycle methods about fragment with activity. In your case, you may use getContext() instead of getActivity() method to get the context of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

getActivity() only available after Fragment is attached to activity. So, getActivity() in Fragment constructor will return null. Check [fragment life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more detail